# Correct way to send emails with pooled connections nodemailer

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I have an array of objects containing recipients and info I'm supposed to send them. However, I can't find a correct way to loop trough an array, send each email, close nodemailer connection and return response. Simplified array:

```
let arr = [
  {
    email: "something@something.com",
    content: "Hello user 1!"
  },
  {
    email: "something1@something.com",
    content: "Hello user 2!"
  }
]
```

I am wondering what is the correct way to loop trough array and send each individual separate content (don't need it to be one content for everyone, but different content for every person in array). After reading everything I could find I came to this solution:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transport = {
  //my mail server auth
  pool: true,
  maxConnections: 20,
  maxMessages: Infinity
}
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(transport);

//this is wrapped in axios with req and res
  arr.map(one => {
    var mail = {
      from: "someone@mail.com",
      to: one.email,
      subject: "Test mail",
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mail, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("Message sent to: " + one.email);
      }
    });
  })
});
```

Now, eventually I want it to stop executing this script (after it's done sending all the emails) - where should (and should I?) close nodemailer connection and return some response? After the loop? After transporter.sendMail()? Thank you for your input!

Comment: I was wondering the same. 

Answer (score 0):

pooled smtp if pooled is used then nodemailer keeps a fixed amount of connections
i have searched it from nodemailer account
https://www.bing.com/search?q=pooled+smtp&cvid=d367f4e7599a49929181c1820e361b0a&aqs=edge..69i57j69i60l3.3992j0j1&pglt=41&FORM=ANNTA1&PC=HCTS

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).